# 配布アニメーションを入れたが、表情だけ動かない

Tags: unity3d

Unityを始めたての初心者です。

配布されているアニメーションを入れてMV作成を行っているのですが、体は動くものの、本来あるはずの顔の動きが一切ありません。
調べてもそれについて言及されているサイトはあまり見つかりませんでした。

- 使っているアニメーション: [こちら](https://youtu.be/JWHqBNQL9xQ?si=eugBJ0OzcmYA7dM1)のをお借りしています。
- Unityのバージョン: 2022.3.21f1

どうしても作りたいので教えていただきたいです！